# Refused to frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive:

Tags: php, laravel, payu, content-security-policy

I am facing a problem integrating the `Checkout Plus` payment gateway in my laravel application. While executing the JS code I am facing an error of CSP.

```
Refused to frame 'https://test.payu.in/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' *.facebook.com payments.np.flydubai.com *.instagram.com *.meta.com *.myshopify.com".
```

I tried to add the following headers on the page

```
<?php 

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");
header('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW FROM *');
header("Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' *.payu.in *.facebook.com payments.np.flydubai.com *.instagram.com *.meta.com *.myshopify.com *.payubiz.in *.payumoney.com *.google.com https://test.payu.in/; frame-src 'self' *.payu.in *.google.com https://test.payu.in/;");
```

Also tried same to add via middleware but the error is same every time.

Comment: Adding headers on your end won't fix this. The owner of `test.payu.in` is in control of this, _they_ specify, which other sites are allowed to frame theirs.

Comment: Do you know how to fix that from PayU?

Comment: Maybe you are not passing the correct parameters, for it to respond with the correct headers so that framing under your domain would be allowed. Hard to say, without seeing any relevant code, and the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

Like mentioned in the comments, owner of test.payu.in is the only one who can change the headers. You can't change that behaviour on your end.

If you're using iframes, you should check the [official documentation on handling iframes](https://developers.payu.com/europe/docs/card-payments/threeds/auth-page/#handling-iframe).